# loss of precision floating numbers to integers

Tags: java, floating-point

```
int i=187;
float f=Float.MAX_VALUE;

System.out.println((f-i)==(f+i)) ;
```

This prints true. Why does it print true and how can I prevent this loss of precision?

Comment: `f+i` is overflowing, not losing precision

Comment: Also, consider that `Float.MAX_VALUE` is on the order of 10^38 and `float`s hold only the equivalent of about 7 decimal digits of precision.  So, at that sort of magnitude, distinct `float` values are roughly 10^30 or 10^31 apart from each other.  So adding or subtracting something as small as 187 (order of 10^2) has about the same effect on such a huge number as taking a teaspoon of water from the Pacific Ocean has on the total volume of water in he Pacific Ocean: i.e. virtually none.

Comment: @cricket_007: This is not overflow. Per IEEE 754, overflow occurs when the result of rounding, before considering the exponent range, exceeds the largest representable finite number. Normal rounding of `float.MAX_VALUE` plus 187 produces `float.MAX_VALUE`, so there is no overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Representable numbers at the high end of the `float` range are separated by intervals of 2<sup>124</sup>, about 2.028•10<sup>31</sup>. When arithmetic is performed, the result is rounded to the nearest representable value. The mathematical value of adding 187 to `float.MAX_VALUE` is so close to `float.MAX_VALUE` that the result of rounding is `float.MAX_VALUE`.

Thus, `float.MAX_VALUE - 187` and `float.MAX_VALUE + 187` are equal.

There is no way to alter this in the `float` or `double` types; that is how they are designed. If you wish to calculate more precisely, there are other solutions, such as using arbitrary-precision mathematical software or redesigning your calculations.